# Prevent contents of div from bumping down do the next line?

Tags: html, line, innerhtml, line-breaks

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div>
That's <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

The "output" that is going into the innerHTML of that 2nd div is a single word, such that the contents of the main div looks like one of these, depending on what choices the user has selected elsewhere:

```
That's right!            
That's good.           
That's close.
```

The problem is, my output div is not outputting on the same line. So it looks like this

```
That's               
right!
```

How can I make the contents of "output" always be on the same line as the other contents of the main div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div is a block element rather than inline.  You want to use a span instead so use

```
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Div is a block element, use a span instead. Or style your divs with float: left

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
That's <div id="output" style="display:inline"></div>
</div>
```